# Selenium Python WebDriverWait Parenthesis Question

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
user_val = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))
```

Why does EC.presence_of_element_located require two sets of parenthesis? I didn't see the need for two pair so I removed one of them and the code quite working -- I just flew by it like it was a comment.  I added them back and it started working again.  Just curious as to why it would require two sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user_val = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))
```

`EC.presence_of_element_located` is a method that takes a single argument, which is a tuple representing the locating strategy and the locator value. In this case, it's `(By.ID, "username")`.

`WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(...)` is a method that takes a single argument, which is the expected condition to wait for.
Here, you are passing `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username"))` as the expected condition.

Therefore, the double parentheses are necessary to encapsulate the arguments for both the `presence_of_element_located` method and the `until` method.

If you remove one set of parentheses, you are essentially passing the method itself `(EC.presence_of_element_located)` rather than calling it with the specified arguments, which leads to incorrect behavior.